# How to click the specific date from the specific month from the date picker on abhibus.com

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Here is the DOM/HTML [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV8v3.png)

I need an xpath where i need to select the desired date from the desired month from the date picker.
Eg: desired date = 31 and desired month = december/january/february

Here are my xpaths to select a respective date from different months:

```
//div[@class='ui-datepicker-title']//span[text()='December']//..//..//..//table//a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

xpath: //td[@data-month='11']//a[text()='31']

Above Xpath matches December 31st and for January you can change data-month attribute value as '0' and for February '1' and so on... and replace day with 31.

In order to pick month select a value from 0-11 and for date 1-(31 or 30 or 28 or 29).